# Parameter 0 of constructor in .JobSeekerService required a bean of type JobSeekerRepository that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

I reviewed all of the questions about this topic but still can not solve the issue. Annotated service and repository classes with the required annotations but still spring can't see my JobSeekerRepository. I probably missed something but working on the issue for like 1hr so I decided to ask you guys.

Here is my JobSeekerService class.

```
package com.example.jobsearchsiteproject.services;


import com.example.jobsearchsiteproject.dto.JobSeekerDTO;
import com.example.jobsearchsiteproject.exception.EntityNotFoundException;
import com.example.jobsearchsiteproject.map.JobSeekerMapper;
import com.example.jobsearchsiteproject.model.JobSeeker;
import com.example.jobsearchsiteproject.repository.JobSeekerRepository;


import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;


@Service
@Slf4j
public class JobSeekerService {


    private final JobSeekerRepository jobSeekerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public JobSeekerService(JobSeekerRepository jobSeekerRepository) {
        this.jobSeekerRepository = jobSeekerRepository;
    }

    public List<JobSeeker> getAllJobSeekers() {
        List<JobSeeker> allCourses = jobSeekerRepository.findAll();
        return allCourses;
    }

    public JobSeeker getById(Long id) {
        Optional<JobSeeker> byId = jobSeekerRepository.findById(id);
        return byId.orElseThrow(() -> {
            log.error("Course not found by id : " + id);
            return new EntityNotFoundException("Course", "id : " + id);
        });
    }

    public JobSeeker getByFirstName(String firstName) {
        Optional<JobSeeker> byId = jobSeekerRepository.findByFirstName(firstName);
        return byId.orElseThrow(() -> {
            log.error("Course not found by id : " + firstName);
            return new EntityNotFoundException("Course", "id : " + firstName);
        });
    }

    public JobSeeker create(JobSeekerDTO jobSeekerDTO) {
        JobSeeker jobSeeker = JobSeekerMapper.toEntity(jobSeekerDTO);
        return jobSeekerRepository.save(jobSeeker);
    }

    public void delete(Long id) {
        getById(id);
        jobSeekerRepository.deleteById(id);
    }



}
```

Here is my JobSeekerRepository

```
package com.example.jobsearchsiteproject.repository;

import com.example.jobsearchsiteproject.model.JobSeeker;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface JobSeekerRepository
        extends JpaRepository<JobSeeker,Long> {

    Optional<JobSeeker> findJobSeekerByUniversityName(String universityName);

    Optional<JobSeeker> findByFirstName(String firstName);
}
```

Here is error tree

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=63339:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\egecoskun\Desktop\Univera\JobSearchSiteProject\target\classes;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.7.2\spring-boot-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.7.2\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.11\logback-classic-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.11\logback-core-1.2.11.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.17.2\log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.17.2\log4j-api-2.17.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.36\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.30\snakeyaml-1.30.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.3\jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.3\jackson-annotations-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.3\jackson-core-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.3\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.3\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.3.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.65\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.65\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.65.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.65\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.22\spring-web-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.22\spring-beans-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.22\spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.22\spring-aop-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.22\spring-context-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.22\spring-expression-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.24\lombok-1.18.24.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.7\aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.7.2\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\4.0.3\HikariCP-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.3.22\spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\1.3.3\jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\2.2.3\jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.6.10.Final\hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.3.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.12\byte-buddy-1.12.12.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.1.2.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.6\jaxb-runtime-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\2.3.6\txw2-2.3.6.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\3.0.12\istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.7.2\spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.7.2\spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.3.22\spring-orm-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.22\spring-tx-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.3.22\spring-aspects-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\postgresql\postgresql\42.3.6\postgresql-42.3.6.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.5.0\checker-qual-3.5.0.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\2.3.3\jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.22\spring-core-5.3.22.jar;C:\Users\egecoskun\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.22\spring-jcl-5.3.22.jar com.example.jobsearchsiteproject.JobSearchSiteProjectApplication
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.2)

2022-08-03 14:28:49.976  INFO 3532 --- [           main] c.e.j.JobSearchSiteProjectApplication    : Starting JobSearchSiteProjectApplication using Java 17.0.1 on DESKTOP-0JI2QHS with PID 3532 (C:\Users\egecoskun\Desktop\Univera\JobSearchSiteProject\target\classes started by egecoskun in C:\Users\egecoskun\Desktop\Univera\JobSearchSiteProject)
2022-08-03 14:28:49.977  INFO 3532 --- [           main] c.e.j.JobSearchSiteProjectApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-08-03 14:28:50.541  INFO 3532 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-08-03 14:28:50.546  INFO 3532 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-03 14:28:50.546  INFO 3532 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-08-03 14:28:50.628  INFO 3532 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-03 14:28:50.628  INFO 3532 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 616 ms
2022-08-03 14:28:50.655  WARN 3532 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobSeekerController' defined in file [C:\Users\egecoskun\Desktop\Univera\JobSearchSiteProject\target\classes\com\example\jobsearchsiteproject\controller\JobSeekerController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobSeekerService' defined in file [C:\Users\egecoskun\Desktop\Univera\JobSearchSiteProject\target\classes\com\example\jobsearchsiteproject\services\JobSeekerService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.jobsearchsiteproject.repository.JobSeekerRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2022-08-03 14:28:50.656  INFO 3532 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-08-03 14:28:50.665  INFO 3532 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-08-03 14:28:50.677 ERROR 3532 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.jobsearchsiteproject.services.JobSeekerService required a bean of type 'com.example.jobsearchsiteproject.repository.JobSeekerRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.jobsearchsiteproject.repository.JobSeekerRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

And my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JobSearchSiteProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JobSearchSiteProject</name>
    <description>JobSearchSiteProject</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.24</version>
            </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Junit lib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

package tree is like this

! https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8bDr.jpg

As asked my main is here

```
package com.example.jobsearchsiteproject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class JobSearchSiteProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JobSearchSiteProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Check that the `@ComponentScan` either inside an `@Configuration` class or inside your main class (probably `JobSearchSiteProjectApplication`) is covering the package where the repository is located. Also check if you have `@EnableJpaRepositories` on either one of those classes

Comment: with Lombok, should you not use specific  annotations for constructors in your Service ?

Comment: What package is your `@SpringBootAPplication` annotated class in. The `@Repository` on the interface is useless.

Comment: @QuentinGenet you mean `RequiredArgsConstructor` etc right? I used it but was trying to figure out how to solve the issue that's why I changed it.

Comment: @Lino can you check again? I edited the question.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you check again? I edited the question.

Comment: Remove the exclude. JPA needs a database thus a `DataSource`. You disabled configuration for that, so no JPA, no Spring Data JPA.

Comment: @M.Deinum I will delete that after I set the database connection. Do you think that is the problem?

Comment: I don't think that is the problem it **is** the problem. No datasource, no jpa, no spring data jpa. As I mentioned.